# How to access data in user_struct in user space

Tags: linux

Is there any way, either via existing command or API to be able to get information from the user_struct in user space in Linux?

Namely, being able to get the current number of open files and tasks for a user as governed by ULIMITS

Answer (score 0):

I had a look to kernel source code (especially [linux/users.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/user.c) and i didn't find any syscall definition nor `/proc` entry management...

So i guess that there's no API to do that :-(

So you have 2 solutions:

- you can develop a kernel module to implement a `/proc/̀  entry per users that would dump theses statistics.
- you can parse `/proc/<pid/` entries (directory is owned by owner of the process) and, foreach process that is owned by the targeted user, parse the `fd`, `stat`, etc... files.

Answer (score 0):

a simple

```
man ulimit
```

gives you the general description of user limits, and (at the bottom of the manpage) the 'SEE ALSO' section. There you can find:

**getrlimit(2)**

which means, there is a syscall (manpage section 2) with the name of 'getrlimit()'. So, when you do a

```
man 2 getrlimit
```

you will get all the informations you need for retrieving the user limit struct.

Comment: That will get you the current ulimit values, not the actual resource usage.

I'm referring the below in the user_struct definition:

[link](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/sched/user.h)

atomic_t processes; /* How many processes does this user have? */

Comment: Ah i see. That i don't know.